# Order tableviewcell by child timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I tried with this code to sort my posts by timestamp it doesn't work, each time I launch the simulator the order of the cells is different, I suppose this isn't the way to do it, could somebody explain me where I am wrong...
*I edited the code, now my problem is that the most recent posts are displayed at the bottom and I would like them to to be displayed at the top*

```
        self.user.removeAll()
        for child in DataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print("Processing user \(child.key)")

            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
            //if country == "UNITED STATES"{
            if let uid = value?["userID"] as? String{
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                    //
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value?["username"] as? String , let imagePath = value?["photoURL"] as? String{
                        userToShow.username = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of your issue. Please [edit] your question (don't post a comment) to clearly explain in what way exactly that the code does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you call `DataSnapshot.value`, you're converting the data in the snapshot into a dictionary. And the order if keys in that dictionary is not guaranteed.

To maintain the order of the elements as they come back from the database, you need to loop over `DataSnapshot.children`. See these questions for examples of how to do that:

- [Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-firebase)
- [post on the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/SvMQ5mJ0SI0)

---

For your code this would look something like:

```
ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    self.user.removeAll()

    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
        print("Processing user \(child.key)")

        let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

        if let uid = value["userID"] as? String {
            ...
        }
    }


    self.tableview.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really don't understand how to put this inside my code, could you please tell me more about how to do this ?

Comment: I added an example. If you can't get that to work, edit your question to show what you've tried. Note that we only care about the [minimum code that reproduces the problem you'r asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since your question is about ordering, a lot of the contents inside the loop are going to be irrelevant to that (hence my only printing the key above).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, _I edited the code, now my problem is that the most recent posts are displayed at the bottom and I would like them to to be displayed at the top, it is probably really simple but I can't figure out out to do it_

Comment: You'll need to reverse the children client-side. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314374, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43336976, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43252794 and probable some more from this list: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+swift+firebase+reverse+order

Comment: Thanks a lot, I fixed my problem